# Nested generic with type bound results in compile error

Tags: java, generics

Why does this result in a compile error:

```
Optional<Optional<Integer>> a = Optional.of(Optional.of(1));
Optional<Optional<? extends Number>> b = a;
```

whereas the following does not?:

```
Optional<Optional<Integer>> a = Optional.of(Optional.of(1));
Optional<Optional<? extends Number>> c = a.map(x->x);
```

Comment: the type of x->x is Function<? super Optional<Integer>, ? extends Optional<? extends Number>> after type inference, but when I use:
`Optional<Optional<? extends Number>> c = a.map(Function.identity());`
it still compiles (Function.identity() has type Function<T,T>)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although `Optional<Integer>` is a sybtype of `Optional<? extends Number>`, `Optional<Optional<Integer>>` is not a subtype of `Optional<Optional<? extends Number>>`. You would get the same compile error if you tried to assign `Optional<Integer>` to `Optional<Number>`, even if `Integer` extends `Number`.

To understand it better, replace the `Optional<Integer>` whith `X` and `Optional<? extends Number>` with `Y`. You will get:

```
Optional<X> a = Optional.of(...);
Optional<Y> b = a;
```

`X` is a subtype of `Y`, but `Optional<X>` is not a subtype of `Optional<Y>`, it's a subtype of `Optional<? extends Y>`

Turns out that `Optional<Optional<Integer>>` is a subtype of `Optional<? extends Optional<? extends Number>>`.

Now consider the second case:

```
Optional<Optional<Integer>> a = Optional.of(Optional.of(1));
Optional<Optional<? extends Number>> c = a.map(x->x);
```

Here the compiler sees that the result of `map` should be `Optional<Optional<? extends Number>>` and tries to infer that type in the `map` method. So the mapper function

```
Function<? super T, ? extends U> mapper
```

becomes

```
Function<? super Optional<Integer>, ? extends Optional<? extends Number>>
```

because `map` returns `Optional<U>` and `U` in our case is inferred as `Optional<? extends Number>`

And `map` returns exactly what we need:

```
Optional<? extends Optional<? extends Number>>
```

So answering your comment

> What new information does the `.map(x -> x)` give?

`.map(x -> x)` helps the compiler to infer the right type

Helpful resources:

- [Wildcards and subtyping](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html)
- [Type Inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
Optional<Optional<Integer>> a = Optional.of(Optional.of(1));

//Here the compiler can't infer that you have an Optional<? extends Number>
Optional<Optional<? extends Number>> b = a;

//This would be the correct syntax
Optional<? extends Optional<? extends Number>> b = a;

//Here the map takes a parameter 
//Function<? extends Optional<Integer>, Optional<? extends Number>> 
//the return value of map is exactly the type that the variable is expecting
Optional<Optional<? extends Number>> c = a.map(x->x);
```

Comment: I understand that that is what is happening, but I don't understand why.
What new information does the .map(x -> x) give?

Comment: The map is guaranteed to return something of the type that the left side is expecting. That's the new information, the function conforms to an interface